# Why should we remove trend and seasonality before forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality, trend

Why should we remove trend and seasonality (hence, making a series stationary) before forecasting? If time series has a particular trend/seasonality, shouldn't we incorporate that model instead because its indeed useful?

Comment: Could you point to where you have seen this advice? Depending on the exact context, it is either wrong (as you suggest) or a different way of loosely saying the same thing (i.e. "removing" = "incorporating the effect, then looking at what's still not explained").

Comment: Once you have made a forecast for the residuals after removing the trend and seasonality, you can construct a forecast for the original time series by adding back the seasonality and trend.

Comment: @ChrisHaug I was studying the basics of Time series and its forecasting where I came across the text from an Actuarial science textbook that when forecasting for a tome series is done it is required to first difference and remove any exponential or linear trnad or any seasonal trend before forecasting

Comment: @Henry thanks for some clarity

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons:

It is often useful to decompose a hard problem into several minor issues which are easier solve.
Since we can often think of a time series being composed by several components (see : https://otexts.com/fpp2/components.html:) a natural way can be to model these components separately. It might be, that some of them are fairly easy to explain and to forecast. The simplest things to forecast are deterministic ones like constants.

Components of time series that have a rather deterministic nature are those that change very slowly in comparison to the frequency of the time series. This might be an overall trend or some seasonal pattern.

Suppose your data consists of daily average temperatures and you are interested in modelling the average temperature of the next day or week.
Then you can think of the climate change increasing daily average temperatures very slowly as an example for such a deterministic trend, or how the four seasons in the northern hemisphere effect daily temperatures.
The influence of the climate change or any season is unlikely to change during the period of you interested, so you might treat it as fixed (deterministic).

These effects are rather easy to estimate using moving averages of different window sizes. Having enough data, you can estimate these with high accuracy and thereby you successfully  model one part of your time series.
Now you can remove this deterministic part them from your time series and you can focus on the hard part, the uncertain remainder.

Another reason is, that many time series models rely on the assumption that a time series is stationary.
If this assumption is not met then (parameter) estimates of the distribution describing the time series might not be reliable, nor predictions you make.

See https://otexts.com/fpp2/estimation.html or https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/14.5-apatadlm.html .

For an example that illustrates effects of non-stationarity, see [spurious regression, wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship), or  [spurious regression video by Ben Lambert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eozA46jWBck)